# what is the sample space of n processes which can be assigned to m servers randomly?

Tags: load-balancing, probability

If we have n processes and m servers, what is the total # of outcomes? 
m raised to the power n? ie m*m* .. n times? I think this is the correct answer. 
Or is it n raised to power of m?

Comment: Try it with m = 2 and n = 1, and m = 1 and n = 2, and see which one works

Comment: @rrenaud, so if 2 servers and 1 process, then there are 2 possible outcomes, ie 2^1, or m^n, rite?

Answer (score 1):

Each process can be assigned to `m` servers, and there are `n` of them, so `m*m*m... = m^n`.

More interestingly is if the processes have some run time, and you want to minimize the total time to run them all. Then you have a general [scheduling problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling).